# Escape { } in codeblock regions of a markdown file with Hugo

Tags: markdown, hugo

I have a markdown file I want to render with Hugo and it contains example `CMake` code which uses `{` and `}` for variables (e.g., `${CMAKE_VERSION}`). This seems to conflict with Hugo's shortcode handling that messes up the rendering for the rest of the content.

I cannot seem to properly escape the `{` `}` in any way, especially inside `inline` or `block` code blocks.

`Inline` example:

```
Some text blah blah blah `${CMAKE_VERSION}`
```

or a `Block` example:

````
Some test blah blah blah

```
Some block comment with a cmake variable such as ${CMAKE_VERSION}
```
````

How can I properly escape the `{` `}` to show up as code, without any sort of Hugo shortcode interjection?

Here are some live code links that show the issue: [source](https://github.com/dbaileychess/flatbuffers-docs/blob/master/content/building.md?plain=1#L130), [bad render](https://dbaileychess.github.io/flatbuffers-docs/building/#using-in-cmake-based-projects).

Comment: I just tested same in mine, I could not reproduce it. In my case It generated this line `<code>${FLATBUFFERS_SRC_DIR}</code>. To build....` but in yours its `<code>${FLATBUFFERS_SRC_DIR} To build...........</code>`.  which hugo version you are using

Comment: Locally: `hugo v0.122.0-b9a03bd59d5f71a529acb3e33f995e0ef332b3aa+extended windows/amd64`

Github is 0.108 (https://github.com/dbaileychess/flatbuffers-docs/blob/aab422aac812c73598bdd0b5df1d2b33938aaf41/.github/workflows/hugo.yml#L33)

Comment: are you facing same issue in local ?

Comment: yes (i am typing this so i can get past the min character limit :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out hugo is compiling snippet properly but some javascript code is modifying your DOM layout.
You can test yourself by visiting the same page and disabling the javascript in DevTools.

[image]

Edit: Seems [this is the line](https://github.com/dbaileychess/flatbuffers-docs/blob/aab422aac812c73598bdd0b5df1d2b33938aaf41/assets/js/app.js#L28) causing it ?.